# returning undefined for the function in spfx react

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

tried cascading drop down using 2 columns. but it keeps returning undefined. unable to setState in dropdown function

the values are returning in console, but not able to set the state

```
    private async test(getVal: any):promis<void> {
    ...
    
    var timePeriod = this.dropdown(getval.key);
    log(timePeriod)
    //returns undefined
    }
    
    public dropdown(val: string){
    sp.web.lists.getbytitle("").items.select("").filter("" + val + "'").getAll().the(function (data){
    log(data)
    for(var k in data){
    timePeriod.push({key:data[k].period, text: data[k].Period})
    }
    
    retur data;
    }
    
    )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dropdown function is not returning properly. Also, there are several typos in the code snippet you shared.

You need to create a variable outside your promise handler which would what would be returned after you get the data from the SharePoint API.

I have updated your code snippet showcasing how you address the issue.

```js
public dropdown(val: string){
    let output = [];
    sp.web.lists.getbytitle("").items.select("").filter("" + val + "'").getAll().then(function (data){
        //console.log(data);
        for(var k in data){
            output.push({key:data[k].period, text: data[k].Period})
        }

        /** 
         * The return statement below doesn't have any effect on the outcome of the function 
         * as any return here is for the internal function of the success/error handler
         *
         *
         * return data;
        */
    } );
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped. I am not a SharePoint developer. I work as a data analyst.  This was a specific request from the customer. So gave it a go. Thank you

Comment: Glad the answer was helpful